# Netbeans Go To File Search Dialog Is Very Slow

Tags: ide, netbeans

The Netbeans "**Go To File**" feature (accessed with shift+alt+o) is extremely slow compared to the same feature in Eclipse, which is fast enough to do as-you-type matching. It seems that Netbeans is searching my entire project every time I return to this dialog. I updated to the latest Netbeans and this is still happening.

Am I doing something wrong or missing an option somewhere? Is there any way to speed this up or have it be instant like the Go To File function in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Peter Blaha,

> we are aware of the 'Go To file'
>   performance. Therefore, we consider
>   this improvements in our development
>   plan for NetBeans 7.0, see the section
>   Performance

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 7 beta and it's still insanely slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here too:
http://forums.netbeans.org/post-30720.html&highlight=slow